# Looping MP4 video with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, mp4

I am trying to get a simple loaded MP4 video to loop in the background.

The component name is "videoloop"
and the file name is "OTG_MainLoop_1080p.mp4"

Here is the code.

```
videoloop.source="Content/OTG_MainLoop_1080p.mp4"
videoloop.autoRewind=true
videoloop.addEventListener(VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND, videoPlayAgain, 
false, 0, true)
function videoPlayAgain( event:VideoEvent):void
{
 event.target.play()
}
```

This is the error I get in the console, if it helps any.

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fl.video::VideoEvent@460cf159 to flash.events.VideoEvent.
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at fl.video::FLVPlayback/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::handleVideoEvent()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::setState()
    at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::setStateFromCachedState()
    at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::httpDoSeek()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because **AS3** compiler is confusing your FLV Component's own internal [videoEvent #1](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/VideoEvent.html) against the **other** built-in [Video Event #2](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/VideoEvent.html) which is meant to be used for `Video` and `NetStream` based objects.

These two types are not compatible so you cannot force (coerce) a `type #1` to act like a `type #2`. ...At least not while using **AS3** language.

**solution:**

It works if you listen for the *`event is "complete"`* signal:

```
videoloop.source="Content/OTG_MainLoop_1080p.mp4";
//videoloop.autoRewind=true; //is not needed.

videoloop.addEventListener("complete", videoPlayAgain, false, 0, true);

function videoPlayAgain (event:Event):void
{
    event.target.seek(0);
    event.target.play();
}
```

FLV Component is sometimes glitchy with some re-plays (example: after some loops the video freezes, then plays normal after a few seconds). I think it depends on encoder settings when outputting the video file.

You might prefer using the `NetStream` and `Video` API to handle video playback.

```
//# setup Video object and related Net Stream/Connection objects
var vidloop:Video = new Video(); addChild(vidloop);
vidloop.width = stage.stageWidth; vidloop.height = stage.stageHeight;

var vidNC:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); vidNC.connect(null);
var vidNS:NetStream = new NetStream(vidNC); vidloop.attachNetStream(vidNS);

//# metadata handler to correctly display video
var metaListener :Object = new Object(); metaListener = { onMetaData: process_Metadata };
vidNS.client = metaListener;

//# play video file
vidNS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, videoStatusHandler); //checks for ending
vidNS.play("Content/OTG_MainLoop_1080p.mp4");


function videoStatusHandler (event:NetStatusEvent):void 
{
    if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") //buffer is empty when video ends...
    {
        //# ...so rewind and play again.
        vidNS.seek(0); vidNS.resume();
    }
}


function process_Metadata (in_Data :Object):void
{
    //check metadata like width, height, duration etc
    //trace("duration is : " + in_Data.duration );
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so very much, First one worked, but I am going to take both bits of code with me. Thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong also, I really appreciate it so much :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved now. While [**NetStream**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) might seem chunky it is more powerful (inc: webcam, live streams, etc). Only tedious issue is to create own user interface but that's easy.